# How do I import a CSV with numerous date columns into a table using SQL statements in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, etl, dynamic-sql

Say I have a CSV which looks a bit like this:

---

Year 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010, 2009, etc.

Blue, 47, 11, 23, 45, etc.

Red, 32, 73, 52, 88, etc.

Green, 68, 92, 433, 42, etc.

where the number of years is too tedious to enter in by hand as separate columns.

---

And I'd like to load all this info into a table

Blob{Color, year, amount}

How would I go about doing this programatically in MySQL (or any other SQL)?
I get that you can import CSV data into a table with a LOAD DATA INFILE, but my table doesn't have anything like the structure of the CSV. Do I really have to first write a CREATE TABLE listing every single year number in the data set as attributes before iterating over all the elements to put it in 'Blob'? Surely there's a more programatic way of doing things.

Comment: Computers don't get bored. The code to do this given you can assume, the matrix is not jagged isn't that difficult. Wouldn't bother with load data infile though, more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I learned two things from your comment:  i) Apparently the code is simple and ii) You wouldn't bother with load data in file.  Unfortunately, neither of these helps me with my problem.

Comment: You could also do it in Excel (i.e. generate a formula to create INSERT statements), but I can't tell from your data example to give you an idea how to do this....

Comment: If you wish to persist with load data infile, then prepare for extreme tedium. If you don't want to create a bucket loads of tables and write yards of sql, use something other than sql. If you need help with the code. Choose a suitable language, make an attempt and post if you struggle.

Comment: Basically what you have is the output of a pivot query. to use load data infile, you'd have to create a table with the same number of columns as you have years, and then unpivot. Both are painful.

Comment: OK thanks.  It seems that the consensus view is that it would be perverse to attempt this problem using programmatic SQL statements.  But what approach would you suggest?

Comment: Hold hard, posting some pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

In psuedo code using three simple arrays, assuming RGB rows are always in that order

```
open the file
load the first line
chop off 'Year,'
split by ',' in to an array of years
create a 2d array, where one on the values is colour the other is column position
load the next line, chop off the color, split by ',' and stores as say Colours[Red]
do the same for the green and blue rows
close the file
```

then say something like

```
for index = 0 to years.length - 1 do
  for colour = red to blue
    sql = 'Insert Table Blob(year,colour,amount) values(years[index], colour, colours[colour][index])'
    execute the sql
  end for
end for
```

You could make this more efficient probably, whether it's worth would be dependent on volume and frequency.

Comment: Thanks, this might give me something to go on.  Also: doing a bit of Googling it looks to me like my initial CSV could be in the form of something called a 'pivot table', so I'm also going to look at examples of how to 'unpivot' data in MySQL.